# Find what element if checked exactly with * star selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of textboxes that I gave attributes with jQuery `.addClass("error")`. On submit I want to check if any of the textboxes have class `error` so a message telling the user exactly which textbox has an error pops up. I am using this if:

```
if ($("*").hasClass("error")  ){

}
```

With the `*` it checks all the textboxes to see if they have error. How do I get the `id` or any indication of which element has the error?

Comment: Why not just `$('input.error')`? Then you can loop over them and retrieve the properties of the element that you need. The `$('*')` selector is an incredibly inefficient method to use.

Comment: $(".error").each(function(){
console.log($(this)..attr("id"));
});
You can get ids this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$('*')` selector is a very inefficient method to use as it returns literally every element in the DOM, which will be slow. Instead you could retrieve only the `input` elements which have the `error` class, and loop over them to get the information you need. Try this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    var $inputs = $('input.error');
    if ($inputs.length) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission
        $inputs.each(function() {
            console.log(this.id);
            // work with the input here...
        });
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory, that worked. As you guessed i am new to this and didn't know that my method was inefficient. thanks again!